# PowerPoint imported images as JPG for memory reduction

Tags: windows-7

How do you get PowerPoint to save all images, by default, as JPG?  The issue is that I now import the image, then have to remember to cut it then paste special as JPG.  There used to be a switch that saved all embedded images as JPG for reduced memory use.

Answer (score 0):

Pictures that you insert from a file are embedded in your presentation. You can reduce the size by linking to a picture instead. In the Insert Picture dialog box, click the picture that you want to insert, click the arrow **next to Insert**, and then click Link to File.